# Serializing an ObservableCollection(of T) in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, serialization, observablecollection

I'm trying out MVVM in VB.Net for a while now and started out with some of my entities using List(of T)s, which I xml serialized to disk. Now, I updated the classes used by the Lists to implement INotifyPropertyChanged so I also changed the List(of T)s to ObservableCollection(of T)s.

After which, the XML serializer stopped working :'( A colleague told me that ObservableCollections, unlike generic Lists, are not serializable.

If so then how can I make them Serializable? Thanks in Advance~! :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your college is half correct.  `ObservableCollection(Of T)` is indeed serializable but it is so through the binary serializer, not the XML one.

What you can do to work around this to wrap the serialization of any collections of `ObservableCollection(Of T)` with `List(Of T)`.  Just do the conversion at the point of serialization.

For example ...

```
Public Sub Serialize(ByVal col as ObservableCollection(Of Integer))
  Dim list = New List(Of Integer)(col)
  ReallySerialize(list)
End Sub

Public Function Unserialize() As ObserableCollection(Of Integer)
  Dim list = ReallyUnserialize()
  return New ObservableCollection(Of Integer)(list)
End Function
```

Comment: I should have thought of that~! T_T; Thanks~!

Comment: ObservableCollection<T> is serializable via XmlSerializer in .NET 4.0 becuase the CollectionChanged event has been marked with [NonSerializedAttribute]. So if you are using .NET 4.0, you should be fine.

Answer (score 2):

@JaredPar's answer re only Binary serializer works not the Xml one, the XmlSerializer does work for me (in VS2010).

```
//ObservableCollection<Customer> customers = Code to load customers 

//write to file
   XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ObservableCollection<Customer>));
   using (StreamWriter wr = new StreamWriter("myfile.xml")) {
        xs.Serialize(wr, customers);
   }
```